# Stall on CPU on reboot / shutdown

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, shutdown, restart

I just installed a fresh version of 16.04 on my MSI GE62 laptop.

I had some trouble installing at first, which was solved with a combination of:

1. Secure boot off
2. Fat boot off
3. and setting nouveau.modeset=0
4. Uninstalling nvidia drivers

After successfully installing, I get the following error any time i try to restart or shutdown.

[image: shutdown error]

Comment: Are you able to power on and shutdown?

Comment: Edit: power on and shutdown work fine, issue is only with reset

Comment: same here, both for reboot and shutdown. I have to holw power for 4 seconds to turn off. Could you fix it?